# PHP header('location: index.php') working but not showing

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I appology in advance for my bad english.

I'm actually trying to redirect someone on my home page when the php script validated the data.

**my validation script**

```php
/* validate the data retrieved from the $ _POST (only php, nothing else)
** [...]
** returning an assoc array like this ['flag' => <true or false>, 'message' => "my error message"]
*/

if ($error['flag']) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
    echo(json_encode($error));
}
else {
    header('location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

**my js function to send my data**

```js
// Triggered by button onclick()
function createPost() {
    const URL = "./postFilter.php?submit=create";
    const form = document.getElementById('form_create_post');

    let formData = new FormData(form);

    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //Response
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
            error = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            if (error['flag']) {
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = error['message'];
                document.getElementById("form-alert").style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", URL, true);
    xhttp.send(formData);
}
```

**Here is what i get**
Network waterfall
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR2cE.png
Network first request header
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTnk3.png
Network second request header
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJbsN.png

I don't understand were i go wrong in my code and why i'm not redirected to index.php while i'm actually received index.php

Comment: You're not redirected because you're sending the request via AJAX. AJAX doesn't respect redirects. It would be no sense if it did - because the whole point of using AJAX is so that you can stay on the same page afterwards, without any need for postsbacks, reloads, redirects or anything like that. Maybe re-think your design. If you want to redirect after login, then just use a normal postback.

Comment: Redirect your user in JS part, not in PHP.